# dynamically added option to select is invisible

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-select

I am trying to add options to an empty select.
The problem is when I add an option with jQuery or with javascript the added option doesn't appear I tried to debug the function that add the option it is actually adding it to the html but I can't see it on the web site

The select :

```
<select class="selectpicker"  id="partners_id">
</select>
```

The jquery :

```
$("#partners_id").append(('<option>', {
    value:1,
    text:'One'
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You forgot to add $ in append function.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#partners_id").append($('<option>', {
        value:1,
        text:'One'
    }))
})
```

Append using button click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#btn" ).click(function() {
        $("#partners_id").append($('<option>', {
            value:1,
            text:'One'
        }))
    });
})
```

Comment: I am sure you forgot add document ready function. Add updated code and try

Comment: can you explain more, i am a beginner is jquery

Comment: Please accept the solution.The ready event occurs when the DOM (document object model) has been loaded and there are 2 options to append an option into select.First one using object that I used it above using $ sign and second, you can directly append as a string like append("<option value='1'>One</option>"). If you are appending more than 1 option then above logic would be easy to implement. Hope this clear your doubts

Answer (score 1):

Try add one root option in html and next use `append()` method:

```
<select class="selectpicker"  id="partners_id">
   <option value="-">Root</option>
</select>
```

> The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection

Add LAST

```
 $("#partners_id").append("<option value='1'>One</option>");
```

or

```
 $("#partners_id").append(
        $('<option></option>').val(1).html("one")
    );
```

or Add FIRST, use `prepend()`

> The .prepend() method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection

```
 $("#partners_id").prepend(
            $('<option></option>').val(1).html("one")
        );
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/w7cgmy12/

Comment: i've tried every thing and they all add the option tag inside the select but the option doesn't apear

Comment: Try add one root option in html also or use `prepend()` instead `append()`

Comment: it didn't work ,but i think i found the problem i tried to see the difference between adding it dynamically and adding it in the html code, the difference is that the option is added inside the select tag but it is not added inside the dropdown menu which is generated when we open the website, but i don't know why.